# Ubuntu Server 20.04 network-manager not starting VPN automatically

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipsec, l2tp, networkmanager

I am getting desperate here. I need to connect a Ubuntu Server Machine on a VPS to a network to monitor several machines. I can only connect to the network with L2TP over IPsec.

I have tried installing the GUI on the Ubuntu Server, changing Netplan to use Network Manager as renderer, but this way I can't manage to get the VPN connection starting automatically on boot. I cannot start the GUI tool `sudo nmcli-connection-editor`from VNC because it fails to start a GUI applet with privileges.
The only option I have found is to use nmcli editor over ssh with `sudo nmcli c edit netplan-01-eth0` and trying to set the `connection.secondaries` value to the UUID of the "myvpn" connection.

This doesn't work as rebooting the VPS just removes the value of `connection.secondaries` back to an empty value.

I need a solution to keep the VPN always up, regardless of disconnections from the VPN Server (similar to DPD in Strongswan) and to reboot.

I would love to use strongswan, but I cannot make swanctl to work.

Comment: netplan overrides any settings changes you make in NetworkManager. If you intend to configure your network with NetworkManager, then disable and remove netplan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @MichaelHampton ! Is there a way to configure an L2TP over IPSEC VPN with Netplan? What exact setup would you recommend for this case?

Comment: Ok, I have just deleted all data regarding the connection in 01-netcfg.yaml and just left the version and renderer keys. Now on restart the VPN gets connected. I think I have finally understood the logic behind this whole netplan, networkd, networkmanager... etc...